# motor driver shield covering ports for ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, l293d

im new to arduino and am making an arduino car. the motor driver shield covers the ports (am connecting an ultrasonic sensor) and i know that we can connect it to the 'holes' on the motor driver shield (l293d) but i do not have a solder or header pins. there's a lockdown and i cannot get any of those. can i make a makeshift arrangement? (refer img): it is a little loose, is there any fix using jumper wires or any other arrangement? please let me know![image]

Comment: There is such a thing as home delivery you know...

Comment: my area is under strict lockdown, deliveries have been stopped

Comment: @majenko is there any other fix?

Comment: Do you have a breadboard available?

Comment: Of course any way will be very hacky and non-permanent. Often the pins of jumper wires are actually small pieces of thin folded metal. In that case you could try to unfold them a bit, to make them bigger. That might give them better grip in the holes. Otherwise you might be able to improvise something with materials, that you already have. You could try paper clips, which are typically a bit thicker, than jumper pins. It really depends, what types of conductive material you have. You cannot really advice you further, since the standard way is not possible for you currently.

Comment: try this .... push the pin through the hole as far as it will go ... use pliers to flatten the end of the pin .... gently pull the pin back out of the hole (or push pin from back of board) ... it should bind because of the flattening ... experiment with the amount of flattening required .... start with slight flattening and keep increasing in small amounts

Comment: You might also try very small machine screws and nuts, if you can find any. You'd put a screw and nut through one of the breadboard holes, and then wrap a bare wire around the screw. When you tighten down the nut on the screw it should press the wire against the pad on the breadboard. For this to work you will need really tiny screws however.

Comment: Your home is in such tight lockdown that you can't take deliveries, even those left on your porch?

Comment: You really need a soldering iron with some electronics solder, and ideally some headers. Anything you try and do without a soldering iron is going to be a hacky, poor solution. I would focus on finding a way to get ahold of a soldering iron. Perhaps someone in walking distance of your home has one they can leave at their front door for you to borrow?

Comment: @DuncanC your comment about the screws gave me an idea ... put thin wire through the hole and jam the end of a toothpick through the hole next to the wire ... that should hold the wire fairly tight

Comment: True. Especially if you can use the tapered ends of round toothpicks. However, they are going to be prone to falling out.